# Does an isothermal process always imply an adiabatic process?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, adiabatic

In an isothermal process, temperature of a body remains constant.

In an adiabatic process, the net heat transfer entering into a body is zero.

Since no change in temperature implies than no heat has been transferred, can we say that if we have an isothermal process then we definitely have an adiabatic process as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No , an isothermal process and an adiabatic process are quite different.
Consider the First law of Thermodynamics:

$$dQ = dU + dW$$

This suggests that when heat is supplied to a system part of it is utilised in doing work while another part is utilised in changing the temperature of the body.

So in an adiabatic process dQ becomes 0. So we can say ,$$0 = dU + dW$$
or,
$$dU=-dW ... 1$$

Now consider a piston with adiabatic walls containing an  ideal gas. If the piston is now compressed , volume decreases so negative work is done by the system. From equation 1 above we can see that the change in internal energy will be positive (since work done is negative) i.e the temperature of the body will increase. So in this case you can clearly see that although no heat is supplied to the body the temperature of the body still increases.

For a more intuitive understanding think about it this way:  When you compress the piston you are doing work on the system because of which the net internal energy of the system rises and the internal energy of any system is always directly proportional to its temperature so therefore since the net internal energy rises the temperature also rises upon compression.

Note: in case of compression work is being done on the system so judging by sign convention used in physics, work done on the system is positive and work done by the system is negative (in case of compression) however in the equation for the First Law of Thermodynamics dW is the work done by the system so therefore in case of compression dW in this equation becomes negative.

However in case of expansion , work done on the system becomes negative and work done by the system becomes positive so the value of dW becomes positive and change in internal energy becomes negative i.e temperature falls in case of adiabatic expansion.

Note: System always refers to the ideal gas in the container/piston.

Answer (score 3):

> Since no change in temperature implies than no heat has been
> transferred

This is a false implication . Remember the first law of thermodynamics.
You can have heat transferred into the system and still have no change in temperature, if the system does some work

Answer (score 3):

> In an adiabatic process, the net heat transfer entering into a body is
> zero.

There is no heat transfer in an adiabatic process.

> Since no change in temperature implies than no heat has been
> transferred

That is incorrect. For an ideal gas, no change in temperature simply means any heat transfer to/from the system equals the work done by/on the system, for no change in internal energy, per the first law for a closed system:

$$\Delta U=Q-W$$

Hope this helps.