# Is it always true that a non-adiabatic reversible process is an isothermal process?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, reversibility, adiabatic, carnot-cycle

In a Carnot Cycle, a reversible isothermal process is a non-adiabatic reversible process. Is it always true that a non-adiabatic reversible process is an isothermal process?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does an isothermal process always imply an adiabatic process?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/630064/does-an-isothermal-process-always-imply-an-adiabatic-process)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word isothermal means "at constant temperature", and hence in an isothermal process
$$\Delta T=0\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{Isothermal Process}$$
In an adiabatic expansion, there isn't any net heat flow and we have
$$\delta Q=0\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \text{Adiabatic Process}$$

> Is it always true that a non-adiabatic reversible process is an isothermal process?

No! Consider an example of the process which is not an adiabatic process nor an isothermal process. Consider a process in which the state of system changes from $A(p_i,V_i,T_i)$ to $B(p_f,V_f=V_i,T_f)$ which is called an isochoric process. In such a process,
$$\delta Q=C_VdT\not= 0,\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \Delta T\not=0 $$

---

Everything taken to be reversible!

Answer (score 2):

> Is it always true that a non-adiabatic reversible process is an
> isothermal process?

No. A non-adiabatic process is *any* process that allows heat transfer between a system and its surroundings. Many processes, including isobaric and isochoric processes, involve heat transfer.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A) **Non adiabatic reversible process means:**

1. $q$ is not equal to 0
2. Reversible process i.e the change in state is not at equilibrium with its surrounding while the process is happening, unlike irreversible process.
   In simple words, no integration is needed.

B) **Reversible Isothermal process means:**

1. $\Delta T = 0  $ is the only speciality.

> Using the first law of thermodynamics i.e $\delta U = \pm  q  \pm W$

$q = c \cdot m \cdot ΔT$  where $c$ is specific heat capacity.

For B, we can write  $$\frac{nf \cdot R \cdot \Delta T }{2}= q \pm
W\text{ or }pdV $$

Since it is clearly written in the definition that $q \ne 0$, none of the variables in the formula of $q$ can be equal to $0$. Therefore, $\Delta T \ne 0 $ for a reversible isothermal process.

For A,

$$\frac{nf \cdot R \cdot \Delta T }{2}= q \pm W\text{ or }PdV $$

It states that for this condition that $\Delta T = 0$. Therefore, $0 = q \pm W$.

A and B do not match each other’s conditions since $\Delta T $ of both the processes are not same.

**No, non adiabatic reversible process $\ne$ Reversible Isothermal process.**